# Cannot Archive Xcode Project, Error No such module 'Alamofire'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, alamofire

I installed Alamofire via cocoapods successfully and have been using it when building and running the app on a device from Xcode. Now when I go to archive my project for distribution I get the error:

> No such module 'Alamofire'

I switched my provisioning profile to the correct Ad Hoc profile I've been using for distribution, but since I switched to using cocoapods instead of manually installing Alamofire I've been unable to archive. I tried to fix by setting "Build Active Architecture Only" to "No" under build settings but no luck.

Answer (score 11):

There is a chance of mismatch versions between

[image]

and pod global platform for your project

[image]

Comment: Save my day! This should be selected as answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had different bug with same outcome. Bug was caused by custom build scheme which used wrong configuration to create archive. Archiving reported unrecognized library.

[image]

After changing configuration to AdHoc_Fortex_D_Env archiving recognized all libraries.

Answer (score 0):

you need add `import Alamofire` to your swift files

Comment: clean build and hold Alt click clean build again, it should gone

Answer (score 0):

## Try this in your pod file for install Alamofire

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target '<Your Target Name>' do
    pod 'Alamofire', :git=>'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire'
end
```

I hope this will help you.